# Estrutura de tabela com polimorfia

Tags: banco-de-dados, estrutura-de-dados, polimorfismo

Estou desenvolvendo um CRM e estou com dúvida na estrutura das tabelas, não sei exatamente qual o melhor caminho a seguir para não ter problemas de performance e também não misturar os dados, eu acabei chegando em 3 opções.

**Opção 1:** Utilizar uma tabela centralizada com as colunas em comum entre as entidades e utilizar outras duas auxiliares para complementar os dados, segue a diagramação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Opção 2:** Utilizar uma tabela individual para cada entidade e realizar polimorfia nas tabelas de telefone, endereço, e-mail, segue a diagramação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Opção 3:** Utilizar uma única tabela para as duas e todos os campos serem opcionais, incluir uma flag is_organization para diferenciar as duas entidades, segue a diagramação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por qual caminho vocês seguiriam?

**Complementando:** Houve um erro no terceiro exemplo, a tabela endereço não deveria existir, ela só aparece no segundo exemplo apenas para evitar colunas redundantes, ela deve ser 1:1